# how to manually add simulators in blackberry eclipse?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

Is there any way to add a simulator manually in my eclipse? In android SDK,we have options for selecting various emulators.Likewise,is there any way so that I can choose any one from the various simulators available?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, it can do it. Download simulators from RIM's [Software Download for Device Simulators](https://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477) page and you can see how to add them from the support forum thread: [how to add another simulator to eclipse](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-add-another-simulator-to-eclipse/td-p/652859)

Answer (score 3):

As Ajmal said when you install a simulator it will be added to your simulator list in Eclipse. Select a simulator from "Device" dropdown menu within run configurations as shown in screenshot. The sim package number will correspond to a simulator you installed.

[image]

Comment: when i m installing simulator ,i m no longer able to show that emulator in dropdown..any solution??