# How to add new simulator in blackberry JDE?

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I am using standard blackberry editor from blackberry (not the eclipse) for OS 6.0.the simulator  came with it is for model 9800 Torch but i want to use it for  Bold 9650.I had downloaded the Bold 9650 simulator from web and installed on machine but i dont know how to add it in JDE 6 to use. so any help please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the top right corner of the JDE window, there is a ComboBox for installed simulators. Check if the simulator `Bold 9650` is in there.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [how to manually add simulators in blackberry eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7510421/396949) question.

Comment: @MrVincenzo not a duplicate since he's asking about RIM's IDE which is called BlackBerry JDE.

Comment: @MisterSmith How RIM's IDE differs from Eclipse with installed BlackBerry plugin? As far as I can recall, RIM's IDE was just a plugin until version 1.3. From version 1.3, Eclipse and BlackBerry plugin are bundled together (the plugin comes preinstalled in Eclipse).

Comment: @MrVincenzo That's not correct. RIM's JDE is a legacy Java standalone app. You don't need eclipse installed to run it. Very different from eclipse plugin which is more modern and is now the IDE of choice. Still you can download the old JDE here: https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/jde.

Comment: @MisterSmith Your are correct. My bad - it not a duplicate. I wasn't aware of the existence of of BlackBerry legacy JDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newly installed simulators should appear in the BlackBerry JDE automatically.  If you have multiple versions of the BlackBerry JDE, the installer only configures the simulator for one of them.  Refer to this article for the steps to copy the configuration files to other installations of the BlackBerry JDE.

[BlackBerry JDE does not recognize previously installed simulators](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-JDE-does-not-recognize-previously-installed/ta-p/446083)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Mark!  We definitely can use some more BB knowledge :)